# How do I create method that directly mutates the variable without returning anything?

Tags: python, methods

Example,

```
a = ["*", "s", "u", "y"]
a.pop()
output:
a = ['*', 's', 'u']
```

I want to create similar method, how do I do that?

Update: As proposed by @azro I'm updating this OP with his advice for str, I'll try to replicate the same for the list (basically I'll just change str to list).

```
class WeirdClass:
    value: list

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def weird(self):
        self.value = self.value * 2

    def __list__(self):
        return self.value


a = WeirdClass(["a", 9]) 
print(a)  # Got <__main__.WeirdClass object at 0x000001EB64E32FD0> ; Expected ["a", 9]

a.weird() 
print(a)  # Got <__main__.WeirdClass object at 0x000001EB64E32FD0> ; Expected ['a', 9, 'a', 9]
```

Comment: You write a class that holds internal state and implement a method on the class instance that modified said state ... maybe you want to do some Python tutorials on classes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`__str__`](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-str-method-in-python) method is here to build a nice representation of you instance, as a string. It isn't related AT ALL with the attributs types

#### Generic Example

```
class WeirdClass:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}:[{self.value1}-{self.value2}]"

a = WeirdClass("a", 9)
print(a)  # WeirdClass:[a-9]
```

---

You need your own class to make the logic

```py
class WeirdClass:
    value: str

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def weird(self):
        self.value = self.value * 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


a = WeirdClass("hey")
print(a)  # hey

a.weird()
print(a)  # heyhey
```

---

Example with `self.value` be a `list`

```
class WeirdClass:
    value: list[str]
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def weird(self):
        self.value = self.value * 2  # duplicate list
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

a = WeirdClass(["a", 9])
print(a)  # ['a', 9]

a.weird()
print(a)  # ['a', 9, 'a', 9]
```

Comment: This is not what I meant, I meant creating a method that works like list.pop! Example, a = "OK", now if I do a.weird() a will be changed to, a="Works!", Notice that .weird method didn't return a value.

Comment: The same thing I tried with lists but it's not working as expected!

Comment: So, can you make an example that does the same, but for lists? @azro